# If two predictors in a logistic regression are highly correlated, what is the effect on the coefficients?

Tags: regression, logistic

In a logistic regression model, if I have two predictors that are very correlated with each other, how would this impact the coefficient estimates?

Comment: They will be more variable than they would have otherwise been.

Comment: There are many similar Qs on site. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115915/how-to-evaluate-collinearity-or-correlation-of-predictors-in-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158688/how-should-strongly-correlated-covariates-for-logistic-regression-be-treated