# How can a regression be significant yet all predictors be non-significant?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

My multiple regression analysis model has a statistically significant F value however all beta values are statistically non-significant.

All the regression assumptions are met. No multicollinearity was found. Correlations among all predictors are all less than 0.60.

What else might be the cause of the insignificant predictors?

Comment: See also here: [f-and-t-statistics-in-a-regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/), & for a discussion of the opposite case, see here: [significant t-test vs non-significant F-statistic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24720/significance-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression-significant-t-test-vs-non-sig).