# Dropping a variable from a multiple linear regression model, causes another to become non-significant

Tags: regression, estimation, stata, linear-model

Suppose we have a regression model that measures college Grade Point Averages. The variables that we are using are `hsize` (the size of the graduating class in hundreds), `hsize squared`, `sat` (SAT Scores), `female`, and `athlete`.

After estimating for the model using STATA, athletes had a coefficient of .1693, with a T value of 4, and a P Value of 0.

If I remove SAT scores from the model, athletes coefficient changes to 0.00544 and its new p-value is a whopping .903 with a t value of 0.12.

What I'm asking is what could explain the change in the estimated effect of being an athlete in this model.

Comment: Basic question like this are almost always duplicates - [How can adding a 2nd IV make the 1st IV significant?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28474/how-can-adding-a-2nd-iv-make-the-1st-iv-significant) Also essentially duplicated [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/factor-significant-within-model-but-non-significant-after-drop) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/univariate-non-significant-results-becoming-significant-on-multivariate-analysis). That took approx 40 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It means that being an athlete is only an important predictor of GPA after controlling for SAT score.

What I would do to explicate this is make a scatter plot with SAT on the X axis, GPA on the Y axis, and different color dots for athletes and non-athletes. Then I'd smoothed lines to each set of dots.