# X and Y are not correlated, but X is significant predictor of Y in multiple regression. What does it mean?

Tags: regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a regression be significant yet all predictors be non-significant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/how-can-a-regression-be-significant-yet-all-predictors-be-non-significant)

X and Y are not correlated (-.01); however, when I place X in a multiple regression predicting Y, alongside three other (related) variables, X and two other variables are significant predictors of Y. Note that the two other variables are significantly correlated with Y.

How should I interpret these findings? X predicts unique variance in Y, but since these are not correlated, it is somehow difficult to interpret.

I know of opposite cases (i.e., two variables are correlated but regression is not significant) and those are relatively simpler to understand from a theoretical and statistical perspective.