# how to interpret the result of significant regression of binary logistic yet all predictor is insignificant

Tags: logistic, binary-data

I am performing research on Product attributes of mineral water toward purchase decision. 
However, the result of -2log likelihood test showed that my model is fit enough yet my result of Hosmer and Lemeshow is only 0.121. However, my Wald statistics showed none of my independent variables were statistically significant.

How should I interpret this result?

Comment: This question is answered for multivariate regression at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500.  The reasons given there apply equally well to logistic regression.

Comment: @whuber Is "multivariate" a slip for "multiple" (not that the key point doesn't generalise)?

Comment: In addition to that, something else in particular to logistic models is that complete (essentially perfect prediction) or quasi-complete separation ("near"-perfect prediction, not sure how else to describe) can also result in a significant LRT but no significant variables (whose coefficients and SE will also be seriously inflated)

Comment: Thanks @Nick: that was indeed a slip. I meant *multiple regression,* not multivariate regression.