# Variables correlated but not significant predictors of dependent variable in multiple regression

Tags: regression

Two of my independent variables are correlated with the dependent variable but in multiple regression they turned out to be insignificant predictors of the same.

Is it possible? and how to report this difference in data interpretation?

Comment: Entirely possible and indeed very common. Significance of predictors will depend on what else is in the model. Should be discussed in any decent regression text or course. Similar issues discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/how-can-a-regression-be-significant-yet-all-predictors-be-non-significant

Comment: It's even possible with *only* those two variables in the model. Consider a simple case, where $Y$ is correlated with $x_1$ and $x_2$. *Very* highly correlated. But now, on closer examination, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are almost perfectly correlated. Then *each* will be insignificant in the multiple regression. Examples are easily constructed.