# Relationship Between Correlation and Multicollinearity

Tags: multiple-regression

Suppose I've a model such as

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \cdots + \beta_k X_k + \epsilon$.

Now, there's high correlation between $X_1$ & $X_2$ (say over 60% but below 75%). Does that means this model has multicollinearity problem? Is there any relationship between highly correlated variables & multicollinearity? If there's any short literature on this topic?

Comment: Several relevant threads here e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/is-there-an-intuitive-explanation-why-multicollinearity-is-a-problem-in-linear-r

Comment: and this one is relevant too http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70899/3277

Comment: Also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38093/how-to-deal-with-high-correlation-among-predictors-in-multiple-regression

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. I actually looked for my question in the forum before asking this one. But I didn't get it earlier. So, had to ask this question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

The variance inflation factor (VIF) quantifies the severity of multicollinearity in an ordinary least squares regression analysis:

$$
VIF=\frac{1}{1-r^2}
$$

Where r is the correlation between two independent variables such as $X1$ and $X2$ (Technically, $r^2$ is called the coefficient of determination, but it equals the squared correlation). We usually say there's collinearity if $VIF \geq 10$. In your case, $VIF=\frac{1}{1-0.75^2}=2.29$. So we can say there's no collinearity problem between $X1$ and $X2$. If you use `R` for modeling, the VIF can be easily checked by `vif(fit)`.

Answer (score 2):

Correlation is neither necessary nor sufficient for collinearity problems, although perfect correlation will cause problems.  The best way to test for collinearity is with condition indices.

See [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38095/686)

Comment: Peter, when you can just link to another answer, the question almost certainly is a duplicate and ought to be closed as such.