# How to interpret coefficients from a polynomial model fit?

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to create a second order polynomial fit to some data I have. Let's say I plot this fit with `ggplot()`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(foo, bar)) + geom_point() + 
       geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~poly(x, 2))
```

I get:

[image: plot of parabolic fit with confidence band on scatterplot]

So, a second order fit works quite well. I calculate it with R:

```
summary(lm(data$bar ~ poly(data$foo, 2)))
```

And I get:

```
lm(formula = data$bar ~ poly(data$foo, 2))
# ...
# Coefficients:
#                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)         3.268162   0.008282 394.623   <2e-16 ***
# poly(data$foo, 2)1 -0.122391   0.096225  -1.272    0.206
# poly(data$foo, 2)2  1.575391   0.096225  16.372   <2e-16 ***
# ....
```

Now, I would assume the formula for my fit is:

$$
\text{bar} = 3.268 - 0.122 \cdot \text{foo} + 1.575 \cdot \text{foo}^2
$$

But that just gives me the wrong values. For example, with $\text{foo}$ being 3 I would expect $\text{bar}$ to become something around 3.15. However, inserting into above formula I get:

$$
\text{bar} = 3.268 - 0.122 \cdot 3 + 1.575 \cdot 3^2 = 17.077
$$

What gives? Am I incorrectly interpreting the coefficients of the model?

Comment: This question is answered in several threads that can be found by searching our site for [orthogonal polynomial](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=orthogonal+polynomial+[r])

Comment: @whuber If I had known that the problem was with "orthogonal polynomials", I probably would have found an answer. But if you don't know what to search for, it's a little hard.

Comment: You could also find answers by searching on [poly](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=poly+[r]), which appears prominently in your code. I put such information in comments for two reasons: (1) the links may help future readers as well as yourself and (2) they may help show you how to exploit our (somewhat idiosyncratic) search system.

Comment: You posted a question relating to your use of `poly` without typing `?poly` in R first? That says '**Compute Orthogonal Polynomials**' at the top in large friendly letters.

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah, well, I *did* type in `?poly` to understand the syntax. Admittedly, I have only little knowledge of the concepts behind it. I didn't know that there was something else (or such a big difference between "normal" polynomials and orthogonal polynomials), and the examples I saw online all used `poly()` for fitting, especially with `ggplot` – so why *wouldn't* I just use that and be confused if the outcome was "wrong"? Mind you, I am not skilled in mathematics—I'm merely applying what I've seen others do, and trying to understand it.

Comment: I think I get it - you'd seen the term, but didn't understand that $x$ and $x^2$ (say) weren't usually orthogonal.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

My detailed answer is below, but the general (i.e. real) answer to this kind of question is: 1) experiment, mess around, look at the data, you can't break the computer no matter what you do, so ... experiment; or 2) read the documentation.

Here is some `R` code which replicates the problem identified in this question, more or less:

```
# This program written in response to a Cross Validated question
# http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95939/
# 
# It is an exploration of why the result from lm(y_x+I(x^2))
# looks so different from the result from lm(y~poly(x,2))

library(ggplot2)


epsilon <- 0.25*rnorm(100)
x       <- seq(from=1, to=5, length.out=100)
y       <- 4 - 0.6*x + 0.1*x^2 + epsilon

# Minimum is at x=3, the expected y value there is
4 - 0.6*3 + 0.1*3^2

ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
       geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))

summary(lm(y~x+I(x^2)))       # Looks right
summary(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2)))   # Looks like garbage

# What happened?
# What do x and x^2 look like:
head(cbind(x,x^2))

#What does poly(x,2) look like:
head(poly(x,2))
```

The first `lm` returns the expected answer:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.53815 -0.13465 -0.01262  0.15369  0.61645 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.92734    0.15376  25.542  < 2e-16 ***
x           -0.53929    0.11221  -4.806 5.62e-06 ***
I(x^2)       0.09029    0.01843   4.900 3.84e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2241 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1985,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.182 
F-statistic: 12.01 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 2.181e-05
```

The second `lm` returns something odd:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.53815 -0.13465 -0.01262  0.15369  0.61645 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.24489    0.02241 144.765  < 2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)1  0.02853    0.22415   0.127    0.899    
poly(x, 2)2  1.09835    0.22415   4.900 3.84e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2241 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1985,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.182 
F-statistic: 12.01 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 2.181e-05
```

Since `lm` is the same in the two calls, it has to be the arguments of `lm` which are different.  So, let's look at the arguments.  Obviously, `y` is the same.  It's the other parts.  Let's look at the first few observations on the right-hand-side variables in the first call of `lm`.  The return of `head(cbind(x,x^2))` looks like:

```
            x         
[1,] 1.000000 1.000000
[2,] 1.040404 1.082441
[3,] 1.080808 1.168146
[4,] 1.121212 1.257117
[5,] 1.161616 1.349352
[6,] 1.202020 1.444853
```

This is as expected.  First column is `x` and second column is `x^2`.  How about the second call of `lm`, the one with poly?  The return of `head(poly(x,2))` looks like:

```
              1         2
[1,] -0.1714816 0.2169976
[2,] -0.1680173 0.2038462
[3,] -0.1645531 0.1909632
[4,] -0.1610888 0.1783486
[5,] -0.1576245 0.1660025
[6,] -0.1541602 0.1539247
```

OK, that's really different.  First column is not `x`, and second column is not `x^2`.  So, whatever `poly(x,2)` does, it does not return `x` and `x^2`.  If we want to know what `poly` does, we might start by reading its help file.  So we say `help(poly)`.  The description says:

> Returns or evaluates orthogonal polynomials of degree 1 to degree over the specified set of points x. These are all orthogonal to the constant polynomial of degree 0. Alternatively, evaluate raw polynomials.

Now, either you know what "orthogonal polynomials" are or you don't.  If you don't, then use [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) or Bing (not Google, of course, because Google is evil---not as bad as Apple, naturally, but still bad).  Or, you might decide you don't care what orthogonal polynomials are.  You might notice the phrase "raw polynomials" and you might notice a little further down in the help file that `poly` has an option `raw` which is, by default, equal to `FALSE`.  Those two considerations might inspire you to try out `head(poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE))` which returns:

```
            1        2
[1,] 1.000000 1.000000
[2,] 1.040404 1.082441
[3,] 1.080808 1.168146
[4,] 1.121212 1.257117
[5,] 1.161616 1.349352
[6,] 1.202020 1.444853
```

Excited by this discovery (it looks right, now, yes?), you might go on to try `summary(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)))`  This returns:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.53815 -0.13465 -0.01262  0.15369  0.61645 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              3.92734    0.15376  25.542  < 2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)1 -0.53929    0.11221  -4.806 5.62e-06 ***
poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)2  0.09029    0.01843   4.900 3.84e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2241 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1985,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.182 
F-statistic: 12.01 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 2.181e-05
```

There are at least two levels to the above answer.  First, I answered your question.  Second, and much more importantly, I illustrated how you are supposed to go about answering questions like this yourself.  Every single person who "knows how to program" has gone through a sequence like the one above sixty million times.  Even people as depressingly bad at programming as I am go through this sequence all the time.  It's normal for code not to work.  It's normal to misunderstand what functions do.  The way to deal with it is to screw around, experiment, look at the data, and RTFM.  Get yourself out of "mindlessly following a recipe" mode and into "detective" mode.

Comment: I think this deserves a +6. I'll try to remember in a couple days when that becomes possible. FTR, I think it needn't be quite so sarcastic, but it does a good job of showing what orthogonal polynomials are / how they work, & showing the process you use to figure such things out.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Although I am a little offended by a "RTFM" (but maybe that's just me): The problem is that in all I've read, at least with regard to doing linear regression in R, people sometimes do this, others do that. Frankly, I do not understand the Wikipedia entry on orthogonal polynomials. It doesn't occur to me why one would use this for regression if the coefficients you get are "wrong". I am not a mathematician — I try to follow the recipes because I'm not a learned cook, but I need to eat something nonetheless.

Comment: @user13907, that's not just you. This is indeed a good answer that deserves to be up-voted, but it would benefit from having a nicer tone.

Comment: You don't really need to understand what orthogonal polynomials are here---you just need to understand that they are not what you want. Why might someone want orthogonal polynomials? Submit cov(poly(x,2)) to find that the covariance between the two terms in the polynomial is zero (up to roundoff error).  This is the key property of orthogonal polynomials---their terms have zero covariance with each other.  Sometimes it is convenient for your RHS variables to have zero correlation with each other.  Their coefficients are not wrong, really, they just have to be interpreted differently.

Comment: Oh, okay, *that* explanation in plain English now makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: In which universe is Microsoft less evil than Google and Apple?

Comment: The answer is unnecessarily rude and unnecessarily long. It would have sufficed to say that `poly` in R, by default, doesn't do what a reasonable person, by the principle of least astonishment (RTFM if you don't know what it means), would expect it to do. If I see something looking as a door knob, I expect it to work as a door knob, and I don't want to search for and read manuals on door knobs each time I encounter one. You can equally well tell people to "read the f***ing source code". NO! Reasonable people have reasonable expectations how reasonably designed things should work!

Comment: I wholeheartedly concur with @IgorF. This is is a question-answer site, and telling people the answer while simultaneosly saying "Why did you even ask, why don't you do your own research" is not just rude, it's wholly out of place

Answer (score 11):

If you just want a nudge in the right direction without quite so much judgement: `poly()` creates orthogonal (not correlated) polynomials, as opposed to `I()`, which completely ignores correlation between the resultant polynomials. Correlation between predictor variables can be a problem in linear models (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86269/what-is-the-effect-of-having-correlated-predictors-in-a-multiple-regression-mode) for more information on why correlation can be problematic), so it's probably better (in general) to use `poly()` instead of `I()`.

Now, why do the results look so different? Well, both `poly()` and `I()` take x and convert it into a new x. In the case of `I()`, the new x is just x^1 or x^2. In the case of `poly()`, the new x's are much more complicated. If you want to know where they come from (and you probably don't), you can get started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031172/how-poly-generates-orthogonal-polynomials-how-to-understand-the-coefs-ret) or the aforementioned [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) or a textbook.

The point is, when you're calculating (predicting) y based on a particular set of x values, you need to use the converted x values produced by either `poly()` or `I()` (depending which one was in your linear model). So:

```
library(ggplot2)    

# set the seed to make the results reproducible.
set.seed(3)

#### simulate some data ####
# epsilon = random error term
epsilon <- 0.25*rnorm(100)
# x values are just a sequence from 1 to 5
x       <- seq(from=1, to=5, length.out=100)
# y is a polynomial function of x (plus some error)
y       <- 4 - 0.6*x + 0.1*x^2 + epsilon

# Minimum is at x=3, the expected y value there is
4 - 0.6*3 + 0.1*3^2

# visualize the data (with a polynomial best-fit line)
ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))
```

[image]

```
#### Model the data ####
# first we'll try to model the data with just I()
modI <- lm(y~x+I(x^2)) 
# the model summary looks right
summary(modI)

# next we'll try it with poly()
modp <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
# the model summary looks weird
summary(modp)

#### make predictions at x = 3 based on each model ####
# predict y using modI
# all we need to do is take the model coefficients and plug them into the formula: intercept + beta1 * x^1 + beta2 * x^2
coef(modI)[1] + coef(modI)[2] * 3^1 + coef(modI)[3] * 3^2
```

(Intercept)
   3.122988

```
# predict y using modp
# this takes an extra step.
# first, calculate the new x values using predict.poly()
x_poly <- stats:::predict.poly(object = poly(x,2), newdata = 3)
# then use the same formula as above, but this time instead of the raw x value (3), use the polynomial x-value (x_poly)
coef(modp)[1] + coef(modp)[2] * x_poly[1] + coef(modp)[3] * x_poly[2]
```

(Intercept)
   3.122988

In this case, both models return the same answer, which suggests that correlation among predictor variables is not influencing your results. If correlation were a problem, the two methods would predict different values.

Answer (score 5):

There's an interesting approach to interpretation of polynomial regression by [Stimson et al. (1978)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1177%2F004912417800600405). It involves rewriting

$Y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} X + \beta_{2} X^{2} + u$

as

$Y = m + \beta_{2} \left( f - X \right)^{2} + u$

where $m = \beta_{0} - \left. \beta_{1}^{2} \right/ 4 \beta_{2}$ is the minimum or maximum (depending on the sign of $\beta_{2}$) and $f = \left. -\beta_{1} \right/ 2 \beta_{2}$ is the focal value. It basically transforms the three-dimensional combination of slopes into a parabola in two dimensions. Their paper gives an example from political science.

Comment: +1 For related analyses please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28730 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157629.

Answer (score 2):

'poly' performs Graham-Schmidt ortho-normalization on the polynomials 1, x, x^2, ..., x^deg
For example this function does the same thing as 'poly' without returning 'coef' attributes of course.

```
MyPoly <- 
function(x, deg)
{
    n <- length(x)
    ans <- NULL
    for(k in 1:deg)
    {
        v <- x^k
        cmps <- rep(0, n)
        if(k>0) for(j in 0:(k-1)) cmps <- cmps + c(v%*%ans[,j+1])*ans[,j+1]
        p <- v - cmps
        p <- p/sum(p^2)^0.5
        ans <- cbind(ans, p)
    }
    ans[,-1]
}
```

I landed on this thread because I was interested in the functional form. So how do we express the result of 'poly' as an expression?  Just invert the Graham-Schmidt procedure. You'll end up with a mess!