# Under what conditions does it make sense to fit random intercepts for an interaction, but not the main effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am aware that when specifying the random structure for one factor (`B`) nested within another factor (`A`), we can use:

```
(1|A) + (1|A:B)
```

I am trying to understand section 2.3.1 in the online book chapter 2 by Douglas Bates: http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch2.pdf  which is using the InstEval dataset, which is an evaluation of lecturers by students at the
Swiss Federal Institute for Technology–Zurich (ETH–Zurich):

```
> str(InstEval)
'data.frame': 73421 obs. of 7 variables:
$ s : Factor w/ 2972 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 ..
$ d : Factor w/ 1128 levels "1","6","7","8",..: 525 560 832 1068 6..
$ studage: Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "2"<"4"<"6"<"8": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ..
$ lectage: Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1..
$ service: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
$ dept : Factor w/ 14 levels "15","5","10",..: 14 5 14 12 2 2 13 3 3 ..
$ y : int 5 2 5 3 2 4 4 5 5 4 ...
```

Factor `s` designates the student and `d` the instructor. The `dept` factor is the department for the course and `service` indicates whether the course was a service course taught to students from other departments. Thus these data are partially crossed.

The model fitted in the text is:

```
fm4 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|s) + (1|d) + (1|dept:service), InstEval, REML=0)
```

My question is: why is the interaction fitted as a random intercept without (or instead of) the main effect also being fitted in this case, and in general: when would we fit random effects for an interaction but not for either of the main effects ? These are not nested factors, so I guess that has something to do with it, but why is `dept` not specified as a random intercept instead ? The text goes on to say

> We could pursue other mixed-effects models here, such as using the `dept`
>   factor and not the `dept:service` interaction to define random effects, but we
>   will revisit these data in the next chapter and follow up on some of these
>   variations there.

However, as far as I know, there is no Chapter 3 !!!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=douglas+bates++%22mixed+effects+modeling+with+R

Answer (score 4):

Using the notation `dept:service` you get the interaction *and* main effects. You can see this also in the output where the number of groups are specified as 28.

```
Loading required package: Matrix
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ 1 + (1 | s) + (1 | d) + (1 | dept:service)
   Data: InstEval

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 237663.3  237709.3 -118826.6  237653.3     73416 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9941 -0.7474  0.0400  0.7721  3.1124 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 s            (Intercept) 0.10541  0.3247  
 d            (Intercept) 0.26256  0.5124  
 dept:service (Intercept) 0.01213  0.1101  
 Residual                 1.38495  1.1768  
Number of obs: 73421, groups:  s, 2972; d, 1128; dept:service, 28

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  3.25521    0.02824   115.3
```

Using an interaction term without a main effect would make sense if the effect is only expected in the interaction.

For instance, let $x$ be number of kids in a family and $y$ number of schools in the area. Say there would be some effect that involves the number of schools that is only relevant when a family has kids, then it makes no sense to include number of schools as a main effect.