# significant $\chi^2$, breakdown shows nothing interesting

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals, post-hoc

Someone I know told me that he had performed $\chi^2$ test of independence with Yates's correction on a $2\times n$ contingency table, seen that $p\lt10\%$ (good enough for his purposes), and [calculated adjusted residuals as described by Sharpe](https://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=20&n=8), q.v., only to have none of the categories show up with sufficiently high residuals to stand out. He asked me what that means. I told him that I didn't think that that was possible but that he should probably look to the higher (absolute) values of the adjusted residuals.

- Am I right that that's not possible (so there was some error in the calculation)?
- If it *is* possible, what's the answer to his question?

Comment: This happens all the time, especially with such relaxed standards of significance.  The underlying intuition is that a group of tiny deviations from independence can suffice, in the aggregate, as evidence of lack of independence while none of the deviations alone is adequate evidence.  It is *exactly* the same phenomenon as having a [significant overall regression (F) statistic without any individual coefficient being significant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/why-is-it-possible-to-get-significant-f-statistic-p-001-but-non-significant-r). Indeed, that's a duplicate thread.

Comment: Minor point: Yate's correction makes Pearson's $\chi^2$ act more like Fisher's "exact" test, which is conservative.  Don't use continuity correction here.  And instead of residuals, look at the raw stratified proportions.  More important: don't put such emphasis on statistical significance, as Peter stated below.

Comment: @whuber many thanks. Those answers all point to multicollinearity, which seems irrelevant here.

Comment: [My answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14528/919) points out that multicollinearity indeed is irrelevant.  It is, however, almost always relevant in ANOVA unless you have used a carefully designed experimental arrangement of factors (to achieve orthogonality).

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not right and yes, this is possible.

One way it is possible is that N is large. With a large enough N, even tiny differences are statistically significant.

There's no "answer" except to not rely so much on statistical significance.

Comment: The residuals are divided by population size.

Comment: @msh210 what do you mean?