# How to prove the equivalence of partial correlation and coefficient of partial determination?

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared, partial-correlation

I am taking a regression course. Suppose there are two linear regression models

\begin{aligned}
M_1: & y = \beta_0 + x_2\beta_2 + \epsilon \\
M_2: & y = \beta_0 + x_1\beta_1 + x_2\beta_2 + \epsilon
\end{aligned}

We want to know if we should add $X_1$ in the model (i.e. choose $M_1$ or $M_2$). Thus, we utilize a statistic named $R_{Y1|2}^2$. It  represents the proportion of variation that can be explained by $X_1$ given $X_2$ is already in the model. And it can be defined in two ways.

$$
R_{Y1|2}^2 = \frac{SSE(X_2) - SSE(X_1, X_2)}{SSE(X_2)}
$$

$$
R_{Y1|2}^2 = \frac{(r_{Y,X_1} - r_{Y,X_2}r_{X_1,X_2})^2}{(1-r_{X_1,X_2}^2)(1-r_{Y,X_2}^2)}
$$

I was just wondering why they are equivalent. To prove it, I tried to use some linear algebra.

$$
\frac{SSE(X_2) - SSE(X_1, X_2)}{SSE(X_2)} = \frac{Y^\top(H_{12} - H_{2})Y}{Y^\top(I - H_{2})Y}
$$
and

$$
\frac{(r_{Y,X_1} - r_{Y,X_2}r_{X_1,X_2})^2}{(1-r_{X_1,X_2}^2)(1-r_{Y,X_2}^2)} = \frac{Y^\top(I - H_{2})X_1}{Y^\top(I - H_{2})Y X_1^\top(I - H_{2})X_1}
$$

where $H_2$ is the hat matrix of $X = [1, X_2]$ and $H_{12}$ is the hat matrix of $X' = [1, X_1, X_2]$. However, I am stuck here. If anyone can help me out, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem much harder than it looks (+1).

The expression $\frac{(r_{Y,X_1} - r_{Y,X_2}r_{X_1,X_2})^2}{(1-r_{X_1,X_2}^2)(1-r_{Y,X_2}^2)} = \frac{Y^\top(I - H_{2})X_1}{Y^\top(I - H_{2})Y X_1^\top(I - H_{2})X_1}$ is off, it is much more verbose than that.  Let me first correct that for you.  Using the fact that [in simple linear regression, the coefficient of simple correlation equals to the Pearson correlation between $y$ and $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129909/correlation-coefficient-and-determination-coefficient), we have (to save some typing, from now on I will write $Y, X_1, X_2$ as $y, x_1, x_2$, and the transpose notation $\top$ is written as $'$):
\begin{align}
& r_{y, x_1} = \frac{y'Cx_1}{\sqrt{y'Cy \cdot x_1'Cx_1}}, \\
& r_{y, x_2} = \frac{y'Cx_2}{\sqrt{y'Cy \cdot x_2'Cx_2}}, \\
& r_{x_1, x_2} = \frac{x_1'Cx_2}{\sqrt{x_1'Cx_1 \cdot x_2'Cx_2}},
\end{align}
where $C = I - q_1q_1'$ and $q_1 = \mathbf{1}/\sqrt{n}$ (by convention, $\mathbf{1}$  is the $n$-long column vector of all ones).  Plugging them to $\frac{(r_{y,x_1} - r_{y,x_2}r_{x_1,x_2})^2}{(1-r_{x_1,x_2}^2)(1-r_{y,x_2}^2)}$ and doing tedious elementary algebra gives
\begin{align}
& \frac{(r_{y,x_1} - r_{y,x_2}r_{x_1,x_2})^2}{(1-r_{x_1,x_2}^2)(1-r_{y,x_2}^2)} \\
=& \frac{(y'Cx_1 \cdot x_2'Cx_2 - y'Cx_2 \cdot x_1'Cx_2)^2}{(x_1'Cx_1 \cdot x_2'Cx_2 - (x_1'Cx_2)^2)(y'Cy \cdot x_2'Cx_2 - (y'Cx_2)^2)}. \tag{1}
\end{align}
To establish the goal equality, consider the QR decomposition of the raw design matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & x_2 & x_1\end{bmatrix}$. Suppose $X = QR$, where the columns of $Q = \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & q_3\end{bmatrix}$ are orthonormalized vectors of $\mathbf{1}, x_2$ and $x_1$ obtained by the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure.  More explicitly, there exist real numbers $a, b, c, d, e$ such that
\begin{align}
& \mathbf{1} = \sqrt{n}q_1, \\
& x_2 = aq_1 + bq_2, \\
& x_1 = cq_1 + dq_2 + eq_3. \tag{2}
\end{align}
In terms of $q_1, q_2, q_3$, $\frac{SSE(x_2) - SSE(x_1, x_2)}{SSE(x_2)}$ can be expressed as (note that the hat matrix $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X' = QQ' = q_1q_1' + 
q_2q_2' + q_3q_3'$):
\begin{align}
\frac{SSE(x_2) - SSE(x_1, x_2)}{SSE(x_2)} = \frac{y'(H - \tilde{H})y}{y'(I - \tilde{H})y} =  
\frac{(y'q_3)^2}{y'(I - q_1q_1' - q_2q_2')y}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Here $\tilde{H} = \tilde{X}(\tilde{X}'\tilde{X})^{-1}\tilde{X}'$ and $\tilde{X} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & x_2 \end{bmatrix}$.  It is therefore easy to verify that $\tilde{H} = q_1q_1' + q_2q_2')$.

To simplify $(1)$, replacing $x_1, x_2$ in $(1)$ in terms of $q_1, q_2, q_3$ by $(2)$ and utilizing the orthonormality of the group $\{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$.  It can be shown that (the actual computation is quite lengthy, yet not difficult, so I omit the details here):
\begin{align}
& (y'Cx_1 \cdot x_2'Cx_2 - y'Cx_2 \cdot x_1'Cx_2)^2 = b^4e^2(y'q_3)^2, \\
& (x_1'Cx_1 \cdot x_2'Cx_2 - (x_1'Cx_2)^2)(y'Cy \cdot x_2'Cx_2 - (y'Cx_2)^2) 
= b^4e^2y'(I - q_1q_1' - q_2q_2')y.  
\end{align}
The factor $b^4e^2$ is cancelled out when forming the ratio, hence the goal equality holds (comparing $(3)$).  This completes the proof.

Comment: Amazing! I think the critical step is to use QR decomposition for X and its hat matrix. I did not expect the question to be answered after two and half years. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ForStudy If the answer helps you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Just did. Thank you for reminding me.