# Full model significant but insignificant predictors (NO COLLINEARITY)

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, multicollinearity

A follow-up on [this unceremoniously deleted question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505764/full-logistic-regression-model-significant-but-insignificant-predictors), and before you yet again send me to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/why-is-it-possible-to-get-significant-f-statistic-p-001-but-non-significant-r), keep in mind that, as was re-iterated in [the original formulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505764/full-logistic-regression-model-significant-but-insignificant-predictors), **collinearity is not an issue** here (which is the only explanation brought up in [that other discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/why-is-it-possible-to-get-significant-f-statistic-p-001-but-non-significant-r)).

We fit a logistic regression model with about ~10 numerical predictors, for $n=500$ observations (a seemingly respectable sample size) and got the following:

1. Full model is statistically significant. Here are the ANOVA results using ChiSq test.

[image]

2. None of the individual predictors are significant in the full model. Here is the model summary.

[image]

3. **No evidence of collinearity (VIF scores all < 2, none of the pairwise correlations are >0.5, etc)**. Here is the VIF output for the model.

[image]

And when enough variables are dropped (e.g. via stepwise selection to reduce the model), the individual predictors eventually start becoming significant.. What might be operating here if **not collinearity**?

Comment: Because *the entire point* of my answer in the duplicate thread was that collinearity is not necessarily an issue, I have to disagree with your premise.  You need a better reason to reopen this question.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. I've simply responded to your post on there that appeared most relevant, with same question in a more condensed fashion. Situation you describe there appears to still have considerably more evidence of multi-collinearity than in my example (average VIF is about 3.5x what I get).

Comment: Thank you--that's interesting.  It would help to have a reproducible example we could experiment with.

Comment: You don't want to hear it but the issue may still be collinearity - *any* kind of dependence among the $x$-variables, particularly if more than two variables are involved, can explain such a situation. Correlations or VIF don't need to be particularly high; they are not perfect at picking up any possible dependence structure that may explain this.

Comment: Another possibility is that all or many variables may have a weak influence, weak enough that it is not picked up by testing them individually, but altogether strong enough to be picked up by the overall model.